# Picking two pivot columns

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I wanted to know that if i pick two pivot columns of a Matrix who has 3 pivot columns, then can any of the two columns i picked be used as an orthogonal basis?? Or should i pick all three columns in order to create a orthogonal basis?

First column consist of (1,1,-1,-1)
Second column consist of (3,-1,1,-3)
Third column consist of (2,6,0,4)

Comment: The number of pivot columns is equal to the dimension of the column space. How many vectors do you need for a basis?

Comment: I thought only one for a basis?

Comment: Recall the definition of the dimension of a vector space.

Comment: @amd the dimension is if i pick two vectors then my dimension will be 2 in a vectorspace right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot columns in the RREF are not necessarly orthogonal.

We can choose them to form a basis and then orthogonalize by [**Gram-Schmidt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) process.

Note that with 2 pivot columns we can construct a basis for a 2 dimensional subspace, thus that choiche is necessarly different from a basis with 3 pivot columns.

Comment: So if a Matrix A has three pivot colums, and i pick two pivot columns in order to contruct a orthogonal basis it cannot be done?

Comment: @Mark yes of course it can be done, what I'm claiming is that you need in general to orthogonalize them

Comment: @Mark since you wrote "...then can any of the two columns i picked be used as an orthogonal basis?" and the answer to that is not you can't, what you can do is to pick them as a basis (for a 2 dimensional subspace) and then orthogonalize.

Comment: ok so , i cant create a orthogonal basis for the Col of A , with only two pivot columns, i need three pivot columns to construct a orthogonal basis because the Col A has three pivot columns , is that right what i am saying?

Comment: @Mark Are you working on a 3-by3 matrix? maybe you could show full details of your problem

Comment: @Mark In general to have a basis for Col(A) we need to pick ALL the pivot columns. Then we can orthogonalize to create an orthogonal basis for Col(A).

Comment: i see, its a 4-by 3 matrix , should i post the matrix ?

Comment: @Mark Then if you obtain 3 pivots of course you need to pick the corresponding columns in the original matrix to obtain a basis for Col(A). Yes if you could show the matrix and your work it would be better.

Comment: yes i have posted the matrix , also in reduced form so that we can see it has three pivots

Comment: @Mark Yes I see.since rank(A)=3, you can choose indeed al three vectors column (from the original matrix) to form a basis for Col(A).

Comment: ok, i see so picking two columns and make them orthogonal will not be a ortogonal basis for Col A?

Comment: @Mark You need to distinguish the two parts. One part is select a basis and in this case we need all the three vectors. Then we can orthogonalize. Do not mix up togheter the two concepts.

Comment: yes oke, i see now!!! Thank you alot !!! It can be very confusing!!!